# Loading SSE registers

Tags: gcc, assembly, sse, osdev

I'm working on homework project for OS development class. One task is to save context of SSE registers upon interrupt. Now, saving and restoring context is easy (fxsave/fxsave). But I have problem with testing. I want to put same sample date into one of registers, but all I get is error interrupt 6. Here is code:

```
// load some SSE registers
struct Vec4 {
    int x, y, z, w;
} vec = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; 


asm volatile (  "movl %0, %%eax"
        : /* no output */
        : "r"( &vec )
        :
        );
asm volatile ( "movups (%eax), %xmm0" );
```

I searched on internet for solution. All I got is that it might something to do with effective address space. But I don't know what it is.

Comment: What do I need to do to make this work: `asm volatile ( "movups (0x0), %xmm0" );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what is problem. Execution of SSE instructions must be enabled by setting some flags in CR0 and CR4 registers. More info here: http://wiki.osdev.org/SSE

Comment: First rule of OSDev: first enable, then use. Remember, processor starts in 16 bit real mode with almost everything disabled - every processor feature and extension, that wasn't there when 8086 was developed, is disabled at startup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a memory operand as a *constraint* in the inline assembly. This is much better than generating the address by yourself (as you tried with the `&` operator) and loading in in a register, because the latter will not work if the address is `rip` relative or relocatable.

```
asm volatile ( "movups %0, %%xmm0" 
        : /* no output */
        : "m"( vec )
        :
        );
```

And you need to use two "%%" before register names.

Read more about gcc's constraints here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints . The title is somewhat misleading, as this concept is far from simple :-)

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem to me.

Comment: What I need is a way to load xmm* register from a struct, generate interrupt, save context of xmm* registers, process interrupt by editing state of xmm* registers, restore context, and load struct from register to see if context saving/restoring was successful. Operating system on which this is executed is some basic OS which only supports taking control of system after GRUB passes execution to OS, printing text to screen by direct access to GPU memory and handling interrupts (which is my task to implement).

Comment: Only problem I have is I get interrupt 6 whenever I try to do something with xmm* registers. (Processors supports SSE, ofc)

Comment: What's even more interesting is that loading with fxrstor works, and with movups doesn't... I tried aligning data but with no help.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way harder than it needs to be - just use the intrinsics in the `*mmintrin.h` headers, e.g.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

__m128i vec = _mm_set_epi32(3, 2, 1, 0);
```

If you need to put this in a specific XMM register then use the above example as a starting point, then generate asm, e.g. using `gcc -S` and use the generated asm as a template for your own code.

Comment: Thanks, I know about \*mmintrin.h headers, but I can't use those. I'm working with custom Linux based OS made especially for this project.

I looked at assembly the code from your example. It's quite helpful. Now I know how to load data in xmm* using assembler. But is there a way to load it from a struct like I tried. I need something like that so I can apply same technique to get data back from the register and print it out. I know I can do it by moving each 32 bit component to a general purpose registers and reading them out. But there should be  a more efficient way.